# Create a separate submit button for every section in antd dynamic field

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Ant Design for dynamic forms. I want to have validation and form submission for each section, instead of one button for all. To submit each fields section, just like you can remove specific sections. Like this in a picture:

[image]

But if I click Submit it is applied to all field sections. How can this be achieved?

Here is a code example on Sandbox

[image: Edit AntD Form List - Multiple Form.Item - Dynamic Fields (forked)]

Comment: why dont you just create multiple forms?

Comment: It needs to be added dynamically, and you can't really know how many will there be. I need to somehow validate and submit content for each field section. Now is the case that one button validate and submit for all forms

Comment: The fact that is is dynamically added does not mean you cannot create multiple forms.

Comment: You should create such form fields.  Submit button is one but the fields are all dynamic. so you can add a group of three fields as many times as you want. [check out this](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-items)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear to me but if I understand correctly the root of your problem should be the submit button in the form.
You're creating a single form with few submit buttons in it. and it is triggering the validation for all of them. you should be ok if you just bring the `form` inside of your fields map.

```js
fields.map((field, index) => ()
```

Comment: When I put a form inside of fields map submit button doesn't validate at all but reloads the page

Comment: You should prevent default at submit function.

Comment: That way you cloud prevent the page reload and do what ever else you desire